# Creating a JavaServer Page Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am using a Ubuntu virtual machine.  I need to create a HTML file base on data submitted by a web browser.

Here is the HTML for index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>My First JSP Application</h2>
<form method="post" action="welcome.jsp">
Please enter your name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I put this file in user>tomcat>webapps>welcomeJSP (a file i created)

I also put file, welcome.JSP, in this welcomeJSP folder.

Here is the code for welcome.JSP:

```
<html>
<body>
<%
  String name = request.getParameter("name");
%>
<h2>Welcome, <%=name%></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I then go in my web browser on the VM and type in http://localhost:8080/welcomeJSP

But no web page comes up and says it is unable to connect.

My computer is connect via ethernet so it should be connected.

Any ideas for me?

Comment: Are you able to browse to Tomcat's home page? http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Try typing your project name in the URL. http://localhost:8080/YourProjectName/welcome.JSP or try typing it without welcome.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently all i needed to do was go into terminal and type in "tomcat-start".  Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

well, firts you should create a web application project, this tutorial should help you:
http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx